linux/init.h not found and #include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (simple.c)
I am trying to implement the example in the Silberschatz's Operating System Concepts book. The example is about adding and removing kernel modules. So far, it is given a simple.c file along with a Makefile which print messages about adding and removing modules to kernel, accordingly. My problem starts at the very beginning and linux/init.h cannot be found. I have already installed the necessary packages after getting this error by sudo apt install linux-header-generic and sudo apt-get install linux-source but the error still presents.
c_cpp_properties.json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++98",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}

I added this file because in some topics, there is some modification suggestions but I couldn't understand what to do and I wanted to add it.
There some other topics in which it was recommended some modification in Makefile, but I believe it is about library, not the Makefile because I get this error on VS Code before compiling it.
The simple.c and makefile, and the output by both gcc and make are below:
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

/* This function is called when the module is loaded. */
int simple_init(void)
{
       printk(KERN_INFO "Loading Module\n");

       return 0;
}

/* This function is called when the module is removed. */
void simple_exit(void) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "Removing Module\n");
}

/* Macros for registering module entry and exit points. */
module_init( simple_init );
module_exit( simple_exit );

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Simple Module");
MODULE_AUTHOR("SGG");


obj-m += simple.o
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean

output of make :
make -C /lib/modules/6.5.0-35-generic/build M=/home/anil/Desktop/Operating Systems Concept modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-35-generic'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'Systems'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [Makefile:234: __sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-35-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:3: all] Error 2

output of gcc:
   12 | #include <linux/init.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

First, I installed related dependincies, but it didn't work. Then, I tried to modify the Makefile according to this link but it gives the error Makefile:9: *** missing separator.  Stop..

The path /home/anil/Desktop/Operating Systems Concept contains spaces, so must be quoted or escaped.

I changed the filename to Operating_System_Concepts, the make output is changed, warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel   The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0   You are using:              CC [M]  /home/anil/Desktop/Operating_System_Concepts/simple.o /bin/sh: 1: gcc-12: not found make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:251: /home/anil/Desktop/Operating_System_Concepts/simple.o] Error 127 make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-35-generic/Makefile:2039: /home/anil/Desktop/Operating_System_Concepts] Error 2

@stark but the gcc output is still same and vs code still gives the same error for #include <linux/init.h> header file statement.

In #include macro:
- For standard library header like stdio.h use <> (<stdio.h>).
- For other library headers like linux/init.h use double-quotes "" 
  ("linux/init.h").

This should solve the vscode warning.
About the gcc error, you are compiling the kernel with c17 standard, but I read some where that linux kernel is compiled with GNU-specific c89 standard
(gcc -std=gnu89).
